# How to extract repeating data from XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery, xquery-sql

How do I return all the barcode exceptions (with the barcode range IDs)? The SELECT statement below only returns the first instance of a barcode exception.

I cannot change the data format or the way I get it (i.e. in a temp table) -- only the SELECT statement.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Products
CREATE TABLE #Products (XmlData XML)

INSERT INTO #Products (XmlData)
VALUES 
(
'<Product>
  <Product>1</Product>
  <Name>Product 1</Name>
  <Barcodes>
    <BarCodeRanges>
      <BarcodeRange>
        <BarcodeRangeId>
          <InternalId>1001</InternalId>
        </BarcodeRangeId>
        <Name>Barcode Range 1</Name>
        <Start>12345678910</Start>
        <End>12345678919</End>
        <Exceptions>
          <Barcode>12345678911</Barcode>
          <Barcode>12345678912</Barcode>
        </Exceptions>
      </BarcodeRange>
      <BarcodeRange>
        <BarcodeRangeId>
          <InternalId>1002</InternalId>
        </BarcodeRangeId>
        <Name>Barcode Range 2</Name>
        <Start>12345678900</Start>
        <End>12345678910</End>
        <Exceptions>
          <Barcode>12345678905</Barcode>
        </Exceptions>
      </BarcodeRange>
    </BarCodeRanges>
  </Barcodes>
</Product>
<Product>
  <Product>2</Product>
  <Name>Product 2</Name>
</Product>'
)


-- Actual outcome: only first instance is returned
SELECT 
t.value('(Barcodes/BarCodeRanges/BarcodeRange/BarcodeRangeId/InternalId/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS BarcodeRangeId,
t.value('(Barcodes/BarCodeRanges/BarcodeRange/Exceptions/Barcode/text())[1]', 'varchar(13)') AS Exception
FROM #Products x
CROSS APPLY x.xmlData.nodes('Product') a(t);

-- Desired outcome
/*
BarcodeRangeId       Exception
-------------------- -------------
1001                 12345678911
1001                 12345678912
1003                 12345678905
*/
```

Comment: *"The SELECT statement below only returns the first instance of a barcode exception."* Beacuse that's what you ask for; that's what the `[1]` means.

Comment: Well yeah, that `[1]` added everywhere explicitly returns only the first instance. You'll need another `CROSS APPLY` if you want to get multiple records per node, or an `OUTER APPLY` if you also want nodes without exceptions. Consider using `.nodes('Product/Barcodes/BarCodeRanges/BarcodeRange')` as the start rather than `Product`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use `nodes` to the nodes you actually want here so that you get one row per value of that node. It seems, here, that you should first go to the node `Product/Barcodes/BarCodeRanges/BarcodeRange` and then from that node also go to `Exceptions/Barcode`. Then you can get the `value`s you  need:

```sql
SELECT BCR.BR.value('(BarcodeRangeId/InternalId/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS BarcodeRangeId,
       E.B.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(13)') AS Exception
FROM #Products P --"x" isn't for "Products"
     CROSS APPLY P.xmlData.nodes('Product/Barcodes/BarCodeRanges/BarcodeRange') BCR(BR)
     CROSS APPLY BCR.BR.nodes('Exceptions/Barcode') E(B);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Larnu. That worked. And I see that you need to CROSS APPLY more than once for that.